# MFC CRichEditCtrl::PreTranslateMessage

Tags: mfc

In windows 10 OS, in MFC Dialog based application I subclassed CRichEditCTrl and in PreTranslateMessage I am handling <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>x</kbd>. On <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>x</kbd> I am confirming the user whether to delete text

```
case 88: //ctrl+x
if(IDNO==AfxMessageBox(_T("Do you want to delete selected text?"),MB_YESNO|MB_ICONQUESTION)) return true;
break;
```

If I execute AfxMessageBox, the PreTranslateMessage receives message WM_CHAR with char x right after <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>x</kbd> and in the richeditctrl character x is getting typed.. If I am not calling AfxMessageBox on <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>x</kbd>, the PreTranslateMessage does not receive the message WM_CHAR with char x.

How to avoid PreTranslateMessage receiving WM_CHAR with char x ? I need to confirm with the user whether to delete the text or not?

Thanks

Comment: Not enough information to really diagnose the problem. IDK where the article is where it shows how to write a question. But, personallly, I wouldn't do it the way you are doing. Instead, I would add an entry into your accelerator table for Ctrl-X and for the command ID_EDIT_CLEAR. I'd add a command handler in the view or document class for ID_EDIT_CLEAR and prompt the user there. Then, if they confirm to clear, clear it using your rich edit control But you're doing things non-standard. Ctrl-X is not supposed to "delete." It is supposed to "cut".

Comment: And really, from a UI perspective, I don't like that you are prompting the user for a delete in an (rich) edit control. Enable Undo in the control so that if they hit Ctrl-X, it just does what it is supposed to do. If they don't like it, they hit Ctrl-Z to Undo.